# Trouble seeing WeBlog package contents in Sitecore

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I installed WeBlog package from sitecore marketplace (http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) in my sitecore instance. Initially i had trouble installing package however i retried again deleting weblog.config file. It installed without any issue however when i look into content editor i don't see any WeBlog Modules under Template, System or Layout sections.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything of note in the Sitecore logs during or following the install?

Comment: nothing related to weblog. weird thing is when i view the folder layouts in the server, i see all the weblog files in there. However it just the content editor doesn't show any of those weblog modules.

Comment: if you install other modules, are they able to add items to the content tree?

Comment: i rebuilded the link database by going to Control Panel > Database. Amazing thing is, i can see modules folder under template, layout and was also able to create new blog entry. However,the module folder under System is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Sitecore are you on?  Is the module compatible?  Weblog shows that it's compatible with the following versions: CMS 6.2, CMS 6.3, CMS 6.3.1, CMS 6.4, CMS 6.4.1, CMS 6.5.

Assuming you're on a compatible version, I'd check to make sure the layouts and sublayouts that were in the weblog package were actually installed on your instance.  Open up the zip file and check out what files should have been installed.

Failing that, have a look at the log files to see if there are any glaring errors.

As a last ditch, you may want to try publishing.  It shouldn't really matter in your content editor view, but I view the "publish" feature of Sitecore like the "reboot" feature of Windows.

Comment: it's sitecore65. all the files from files folder inside the package are there. However the content editor doesn't show any of those contents. it's weird.

Comment: If the items are not in the content tree then I suggest installing the package again, and overwrite if/when the popup appears asking what to do about existing content.

Comment: Choose Overwrite option, that didn't fix it either. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: There is also a WeBlog forum on SDN where you might catch anyone with specific knowledge of the module: http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=30